# Multisim - Transient time point calculation did not converge

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, multisim, transient

I have problem simulating this circuit in Multisim:

(LTSpice)

[image]

Here is scheme from Multisim:

[image]

When I run transient analysis, I got this:

------ Checking SPICE netlist for Design3 - Saturday, September 26, 2015, 10:58:03 AM ------
======= SPICE Netlist check completed, 0 error(s), 0 warning(s) =======
Transient time point calculation did not converge
Simulation canceled

Any idea what's wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: LTspice and multisim almost certainly have different [default] converge settings. Version 12 of multisim [seems to come with a wizard](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/A65253BD02F585CD86257A6B0049945D) for theese issues. (So what version are you using?) Occasionally I've had to [tweak LTspice](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Convergence_problems%3F), but I have no experience with multisim.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I use Multisim Power Pro 14.

Comment: And with previous version I didn't have problems simulating circuits with opamps. It is interesting that if I remove opamp voltage sources, simulation starts without errors.

Comment: Try a different op-amp model and see if it works.

Comment: I tried few other opamps and I got same error. I think this problem has something with opamp power supplies, if I remove them, simulation starts without error. But opamp must have power supply to work :)

Comment: If you thought about the circuit and ignored the input voltage the output would sit at about -6V OK? then applying the input would severely clip the output close to about -11 volts. This may be the problem - try feeding in a signal that is 0.1 V pk.

Comment: Again same error. Even if I remove both V4 and V1 (V2 and V3 stays in place) I get error.

Comment: I get same error on Multisim 13.0.1 Power Pro. There is something wrong with this model of op amp in both versions of Multisim I tried. :confused:

Comment: Solved. I made stupid mistake, I didn't connect power supplies to opamp correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power supplies are reversed.

Pin 7 = V+

Pin 4 = V-